# Absolute position of `resizebox` and `tikzpicture`

Tags: positioning

I want to put a calendar below an image.

But difficult with `resizebox`: and change x or y position

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a} 
\\
\hspace{3.5cm}
\vspace{-2.0cm}
    \resizebox{10cm}{!}{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
      \calendar (mycal) [dates=2019-9-1 to 2019-9-last,   week list,
      day text=\%d0,
      month label above centered,
      month text={\%mt} \%y-,
      day xshift =1.0cm,
      day yshift = 0.65cm
  ]
  if (Saturday) [blue]
  if (Sunday)   [green]
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{document}
```

Please help putting a calendar below image A or better a solution of how one can have a definite absolute position for `resizebox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the graphics to the `tikzpicture` (and make sure its width does not exceed `\linewidth`).

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=calendar]
      \calendar (mycal) [dates=2019-9-1 to 2019-9-last,   week list,
      day text=\%d0,
      month label above centered,
      month text={\%mt} \%y-,
      day xshift =1.0cm,
      day yshift = 0.65cm
  ]
  if (Saturday) [blue]
  if (Sunday)   [green]
    ;
\end{scope} 
\node[above=0.2cm of calendar]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=calendar]
      \calendar (mycal) [scale=0.7,dates=2019-9-1 to 2019-9-last,   week list,
      day text=\%d0,
      month label above centered,
      month text={\%mt} \%y-,
      day xshift =1.0cm,
      day yshift = 0.65cm
  ]
  if (Saturday) [blue]
  if (Sunday)   [green]
    ;
\end{scope} 
\node[above=2cm of calendar]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @schroedinger's cat is ok but  one blank page added before

Comment: @latexforti Good point! I fixed it by reducing the vertical distance between the picture and the calendar. Other options include scaling the calendar down by adding, say, `scale=0.8,` to its options.

Comment: @Schroedinger's cat. Can you give me other solution if i want big distance above=2cm of calendar. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti Well, you can scale the calendar down even more. I added something along those lines.